# Unsure why my jquery autocomplete isn't working. (flask/python backend)

Tags: jquery, python, templates, autocomplete, flask

This is my html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data = {{job_names}};
            $("#job_names").autocomplete({source : data});  //also tried .autocomplete(source :data)
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2> Maverick Job Documentation Tool </h2>
    Search : <input id="job_names" type= "text">
</body>
```

Now {{job_names}} is a list of jobs that I am passing in via flask/render_template. I am pretty sure I am passing the list in correctly, because I see when I view source, I can see the list of stuff I want to autocomplete. However, the quotations look to be escaped or something weird

```
[&#39;/path/to/job/a&#39;, &#39;/path/to/job/b&#39; etc...
```

Can anyone see any obvious errors I am making with either this or the jquery?

Comment: Have you tried `$("#job_names").autocomplete({source : data});`

Comment: Just tried it. Did not work. I will update my above code to include this attempt.

Comment: can you post the code for your view ? I want to see what you are sending in your render_template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works.

1.) Make sure your passing valid Array to data 
2.) pass json object to autocomple method

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data = ["&#39;/path/to/job/a&#39;", "&#39;/path/to/job/b&#39;"];
            $("#job_names").autocomplete({source : data});
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2> Maverick Job Documentation Tool </h2>
    Search : <input id="job_names" type= "text">
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your sample list and it worked, so that was the problem, the escaping. Do you know a way to turn the escaped character sequences back into single quotation marks?

Comment: To clarify.. I am getting this list initially in my python backend, by passing dictionary.keys() to the javascript

Comment: python return with Entiy number liek this &#39;/path/to/job/a&#39; or are you appending HTML entity &#39?

Comment: return render_template('main_page.html', job_names=  ['/path/to/job/a', '/path/to/job/b', etc...]

Comment: thanks everyone. It was a definite problem with my array (I wasn't escaping properly)

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are getting encoded. You can do this to decode it:

```
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(data).text();
```

Or you can ensure it's not url/html-encoded to begin with

Comment: I've got a list of stuff that is encoded though.. how would I decode everything in the list and then pass the list of decoded things off to autocomplete ?

Comment: I'm not sure why your quotes are getting encoded, but the string inside the quotes also has to be a valid JSON string: http://json.org/string.gif which according to this must be surrounded by double quotes not single quotes